# Numpy/Scipy: std() using weights

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm looking for a way of computing standard deviations from samples that allows the inclusion of sample weights.

`numpy.average` [does that](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html):

> weights : array_like, optional An array of weights associated with the
>   values in a. Each value in a contributes to the average according to
>   its associated weight. The weights array can either be 1-D (in which
>   case its length must be the size of a along the given axis) or of the
>   same shape as a. If weights=None, then all data in a are assumed to
>   have a weight equal to one.

, however, `np.std()` does not. Is there an alternative?